# Bind two or more Ruby code one line using HAML

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, html2haml

I'm looking to convert the following from HTML to HAML.

```
<p class="date">
        Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
        | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
```

My goal is the keep the Edit link on the same line like so:

```
Submitted about 17 hours Ago | Edit
```

This works however the *Edit* link is below the *Submitted about* ....string.

```
%p.date= "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} Ago |"
=link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)
```

Outputs:

```
Submitted about 17 hours Ago | 
Edit
```

This attempt outputs the Edit code as an a href string.

```
%p.date= "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} Ago | #{link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)}"
```

Outputs:

```
Submitted about 17 hours Ago | <a href="/posts/3/edit">Edit</a>
```

Please help on achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the link inside the paragraph

```
%p.date
  = "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} Ago |"
  = link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)
```

**EDIT:**

This

```
%p.date= "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} Ago |"
=link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)
```

will create an HTML like this

```
<p>Submitted about 17 hours Ago | </p>
<a href="/posts/3/edit">Edit</a>
```

And this

```
%p.date= "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} Ago |"
  =link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)
```

will give a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you Santosh. I could've sworn I've tried that but was receiving HAML syntax errors.

Comment: When you have multiple `=`s, you have to indent both of them. You can't put the first one inline.

Comment: Updated my answer, with why your solution could've failed